# How to update relationship with hibernate?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, relationship

I am using MSSQL and I have `Project` model class which have field

```java
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(name = "projects")
public class Projects implements Serializable {
    protected static final String PK = "id";
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "projects", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Feasibility feasibility;
...
// getters and setters
}
```

And also I have `Feasibility` object which looks like

```java
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity(name = "feasibility")
public class Feasibility implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Column(length = 100)
    private String product;
    @Column(name = "launch_date")
    private Timestamp launchDate;
    @Column(length = 40)
    private String status;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id", nullable = false)
    private Managers managers;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Projects projects;

// getters and setters
...
}
```

Also I have standar `service` and `dao` objects
service

```java
public class ProjectsService {
    private ProjectDao projectsDao;

    public ProjectsService() {
        projectsDao = new ProjectDao();
    }

    public void persist(Projects entity) {
        projectsDao.getSessionWithTransaction();
        projectsDao.save(entity);
        projectsDao.closeSessionWithTransaction();
    }

    public void update(Projects entity) {
        projectsDao.getSessionWithTransaction();
        projectsDao.update(entity);
        projectsDao.closeSessionWithTransaction();
    }

    public Projects findById(int id) {
        projectsDao.getCurrentSession();
        return projectsDao.findById(id);
    }

    public void delete(int id) {
        projectsDao.getSessionWithTransaction();
        Projects cbd = projectsDao.findById(id);
        projectsDao.delete(cbd);
        projectsDao.closeSessionWithTransaction();
    }

    public List<Projects> findAll() {
        projectsDao.getSessionWithTransaction();
        List<Projects> costingBriefs = projectsDao.findAll();
        projectsDao.closeSessionWithTransaction();
        return costingBriefs;
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        projectsDao.closeSessionWithTransaction();
        projectsDao.deleteAll();
        projectsDao.closeSessionWithTransaction();
    }
}
```

DAO

```java
public class ProjectDao implements ActiveRecord<Projects>{
    private Session currentSession;
    private Transaction currentTransaction;

    @Override
    public void save(Projects entity) {
        getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Projects entity) {
        getCurrentSession().update(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public Projects findById(int id) {
        return getCurrentSession().get(Projects.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Projects entity) {
        getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Projects> findAll() {
        return (List<Projects>) getCurrentSession().createQuery("from projects").list();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll() {
        List<Projects> entities = findAll();
        for(Projects p : entities)
            getCurrentSession().delete(p);
    }

    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        return currentSession;
    }

    public Session getSessionWithTransaction() {
        currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        currentTransaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
        return currentSession;
    }

    public void closeSessionWithTransaction() {
        currentTransaction.commit();
        currentSession.close();
    }

    private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

And I can add object to the table using service but I have problem with updating? I am not getting any exception so it is harder to find any problem. I googled many answers but most of them suggest to add 'cascade = CascadeType.ALL' and basically their was not helpful at all. So I decide to ask, what I am doing wrong?

When I am listing data from model `Feasibility` when I am passing it to service update I can see change but it is not updated in database.

```java
System.out.println("|> " + project.getFeasibility().getProduct()); // I can see here new Product as expected
NewProdForm.getData().getProjectService().update(project);
```

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I do not know hibernate very well, but everything looks simple when reading documentation but is not give me expected result.

*EDIT* 
Also I would like to tell I add to `hibernate.cfg.xml` line

```xml
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

And only what I can see is `SELECT` statements, do not see any updates happening, why is that?

*EDIT2*
So I found the issue first problem was, I just `copy & paste` my code from internet without, thinking what actually is going on. 
Second problem, and that solve my issue, was in method `getCurrentSession` I am opening new `Session` which make my `hibernate` confused I should change it from:

```java
public Session getCurrentSession() {
    currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    return currentSession;
}
```

to:

```java
public Session getCurrentSession() {
    currentSession = getSessionWithTransaction(); // CHANGE IN HERE
    return currentSession;
}
```

And that change fixed my issue.

Should I delete post? I think can be helpful for others `clumsy` later, so not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the project entity by id first so that it will be loaded in the session and then make necessary updates before saving, like below.

```
public void update(Projects entity) {
        Project existingProject = projectsDao.findById(entity.getId());
        existingPoject.setAttribute(entity.getAttribute());
        projectsDao.update(existingProject);
    }
```

The code above will give you an idea it is not the actual code.

Comment: I see what you are saying what unfortunately that does not help. I updated my `DAO#update` method like this `@Override public void update(Projects entity) { Projects p = getCurrentSession().get(Projects.class, entity.getId()); p.setFeasibility(entity,getFeasibility); getCurrentSession().update(p); }` and it does not do what I expect to be done.

Comment: You are updating Projects by changing and referencing another existing Feasibilty right? If that is the case then you need to get the feasibility first before calling p.setFeasibility(existingFeasibility)

Comment: So what I want to achieve is to update `Feasibility` table by updating field in `Projects`. I have relationship `OneToOne` between. And I store all `Projects` in list and want updating one of them. I was trying update entire `Project` and also I was trying to update `Feasibility` separately nothing is working.